# Is it possible to retain the stereo-information when using enantiopure compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

In a reaction, there is always a probability that the product will be a racemic mixture of the product's enantiomers. Is it possible to use only certain enantiomers in order to achieve just one enantiomer of a product? That is, would using only the D enantiomers of certain compounds ensure getting the D enantiomer of the product?

Comment: Yes - as long as the reaction doesn't destroy the existing stereochemistry. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_pool_synthesis And in all cases you probably meant "enantiomer" not "diastereomer".

Comment: Echoing orthocresol's comment, please check your usage of 'diastereomer' vs 'enantiomer'. Right now, it's not clear to me how to respond, but I think it could be a very interesting question and topic for chem.SE.

Comment: As is, this question is confusing to me; as my previous commentators, I suspect this is due to misuse of the terms [*diastereomer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diastereomer) and/or *[enantiomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiomer).* *Racemate,* for example, only makes sense when speaking about enantiomers. I’m voting to close this question as unclear for the time being. Please check your usage of the terms and correct them to the ones you actually want to use to keep the question open/reopen it.

Comment: Yes, I meant enantiomer.